# Django tests response object zipped

Tags: python, django

So I have SearchResultView(listview) with a method get_context_data were i zip publications and images. For easy looping in the  template:

```
context['publications'] = zip(context['publications'], cover_images)
```

Now I am testing and I have the following:

```
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='admin', password='12345', email='')
        user.save()
        Publication.objects.create(title='eindhoven')
        Publication.objects.create(title='لحضور المؤتمر الدولي العاشر ليونيكود')
        Publication.objects.create(title='مزامير') #mazamir
```

And this:

```
    def test_search_results(self):
        client = Client('127.0.0.1')
        response = client.login(username='admin', password='12345')
        response = client.get('/publication/show/', {'q': 'eindhoven'})
```

Now I need to unpack zip that is in the response.
I tried the following:

```
list(zip(*response.context['publications']))
list(zip(*response.context[-1]['publications']))
```

But they are returning an empty list. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made an extra context variable for images because I do not have to unpack a zip object. The reason that it returned a empty list was because google translate is not working for search on mazamir (latin to arabic). So it might have worked for zipped objects but it was to much code making it to difficult. So I went with the former solution. In the end i made both zipped object and lists because the template needs zipped object to loop simultaneously.